# How to get a list of Kubernetes Users?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

we have created a Kubernetes Cluster with Azure (AKS) which uses "*Local accounts with Kubernetes RBAC*" Authentication schema. From our understanding, this is Access-wise as close to K8s-Vanilla as it gets in Azure.

From my understanding of cert-based RBAC in K8s (knowledge from the ["Authentication" section of K8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#x509-client-certs)), these are the appropriate steps to create a new cert-authed user/service-account which has the permission to view (get, list, watch) most elements in the K8s Cluster:

1. Create a ClusterRoleBinding named `viewers` for the build-in `view` Cluster Role and add the (new) Group `viewers` as subject, so members of that `viewers` group all have the view Cluster Role:
   `kubectl create clusterrolebinding viewers --clusterrole=view --group=viewers`
2. Create a SSL Cert for the user, which includes the group (`/O=viewers`):
   `openssl req -new -key user.key -out user.csr -subj "/CN=user/O=viewers)"`
3. Create a YAML CSR from that and apply it to the K8s Cluster using `kubectl`:

   ```
   apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1
   kind: CertificateSigningRequest
   metadata:
     name: "user"
   spec:
     request: BASE64_CSR_CONTENT_HERE
     signerName: kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client
     usages:
     - client auth
   ```
4. Approve it:
   `kubectl certificate approve user`
5. Download the signed CRT:
   `kubectl get "csr/user" -o jsonpath='{.status.certificate}' | base64 -d > user.crt`

This cert may now be used with `kubectl` to connect and request all permitted resources from K8s.

Now to my question:
How can I list, alter or delete users created like this now? Let's say, one loses the Cert Keyfile (`user.key`) and can't update the cert anymore without deleting the user and re-create completely? Or as an admin, if you just want to know which users exist?